# Selenium hit websites with different proxies

Tags: java, selenium, proxy, webdriver

```
    String prox = "44.213.101.228:5000";
    Proxy proxy = new Proxy();
    proxy.setHttpProxy(prox);
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.setCapability("proxy", proxy);
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
    driver.get("http://whatismyipaddress.com/");
```

My requirement is to run this same code using threads and every thread should hit that website with different IP's. I have randomly given the proxy address so my question is do i need proper proxy server or can i use any random ip address to mask my original ip. I am not able to understand. Also when i run above code i get chrome page with this error - No internet There is something wrong with the proxy server, or the address is incorrect. According to me whatismyipaddress.com this website should show the proxy ip which i have given.

Comment: "do i need proper proxy server" - yes you do. Proxy server is not just any server. It is a network component which serves for a specific purpose.

Comment: Its not that hard to put it in threads ... I recommend tryibg muliple proxies and also ... when u will be choosing a proxy, be careful, what type of proxy it is ... I presonally recommend a proxy with HTTPS, but HTTP should be fine too ... I think that error u mentioned, was created by using a SOCKS4 IP ... but I am not sure about that ... try free-proxy.cz/en ... There you even see the speed, uptime and latency :)

Comment: @StyleZ I have already put it in Threads. Okay I understood your point i honestly thought i can make it work with any random IP. Can you please guide me how to install this proxy server and make it work with selenium.

Comment: @NitinRathod sadly, I cant help you with installing the proxy server ... I have not done it in past ... but there is alot of tutorials on the internet on how to do it :) ... just pick one and do it :)